# \CodeBefore isn't recognized in the pNiceMatrix environment

Tags: colortbl, nicematrix

When I try the following M(n)WE (copied almost verbatim from the `nicematrix` manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        \CodeBefore
        \chessboardcolors{red!15}{blue!15}
        \Body
        1 & -1 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 & -1 \\
        1 & -1 & 1
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8                     \CodeBefore
```

Any ideas why this happens? Did I forget any packages?

Comment: It works well for me
texlive 2022 windows10
nicematrix May 8, 2022

Comment: Maybe my package isn't updated. Will check.

Answer (score 1):

As per pascal974's advice, I upgraded the `nicematrix` package to the latest version (in the process I had to transition from `texlive 2019` to `texlive 2022`). Now it works.